# Which trace source is used by System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, .net, trace, system.diagnostics

As far as I can see, there are two ways to create trace messages in .NET.

1. The static methods of [System.Diagnostics.Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx):

   ```
   Trace.WriteLine("Something happened");
   ```
2. The instance methods of [System.Diagnostics.TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx):

   ```
   var ts = new TraceSource("TraceTest");
   ts.TraceInformation("Something happened");
   ```

In my app.config file, I can either add a trace listener for *everything*:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            ...
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

or for one particular trace source:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="...">
            <listeners>
                ...
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**My question**

If I use the first method (static methods of System.Diagnostics.Trace), which trace source name is used?

<sub>I've checked the [MSDN page of System.Diagnostics.Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx), but did not find the answer there.</sub>

Comment: I don't think it uses a Source. It acts like a kind of 'global source' . Two parallel APIs, probably a historical relic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That's quite possible (trace sources were added in v2.0), but I haven't found proof for it yet. However, it's also conceivable that they added a specific source for those "legacy" operations.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the source of Trace.Writeline with [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and it enums all listeners and sends the message to all:

```
                foreach (TraceListener listener in TraceInternal.Listeners)
                {
                    if (listener.IsThreadSafe)
                    {
                        listener.WriteLine(message);
                        if (!TraceInternal.AutoFlush)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        listener.Flush();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lock (listener)
                        {
                            listener.WriteLine(message);
                            if (TraceInternal.AutoFlush)
                            {
                                listener.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But forget this ugly Trace calls, use [ETW Eventsource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/07/09/logging-your-own-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx) for a [much better tracing/logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/08/13/windows-high-speed-logging-etw-in-c-net-using-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I do not see how it answers the question.